# Python - Todoist API - Store data into Dictionary

Tags: python, dataset

I've this Python code that allows me to collect data from Todoist API. Now I want to store this data into a Dictionary in order to make some data processing and some advanced analytics. Using this code how can I store this values into the structure ?

```
from pytodoist import todoist
user = todoist.login('####','""""')
projects = user.get_projects()
for project in projects:
    print(project.name)

tasks = user.get_tasks()
for task in tasks:
    print("Project: ", task.project.name, ", Task: ", task.content, ", Date: ", task.date_string, ", Priority: ", task.priority, ", Added in: ", task.date_added)
```

My key_pais: The strings that I've in For loop "Project", "Task", etc.
Values: the values from taks

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what's the key and value pairs for your task?

Comment: @Aditya thanks! I add some more information in question

Comment: It would be better we if you will convert it to a `JSON object` as JSON is in short dictionary with multiple levels

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102573/need-help-exporting-data-to-json-file ???

Comment: Yes that will do but change it to suite your desires..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first remember that a dictionary is just bunches of keys and value pairs...

So, if the key is $a$ and the value is $10$ , you can access the value by doing `d[a]` (d is the dictionary)

Beaware that there is no order to storing the values, you can use OrderedDict for that..

Also you can have two values for the same key in a simple dictionary.

Here's the complete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27102573/6524169)